# Resize text to totally fill container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` with a fixed height and a fluid width (15% of `body` width). I want the paragraph text inside to totally fill the `div`; not overflow and not underfill.

I've tried with jQuery to increment the text size until the height of the paragraph is equal to the height of the container `div`. At that point, the text should be totally covering the `div`. The only problem is that font-size increments in 0.5px values. You can't do 33.3px; it has to be either 33.0px or 33.5px. So at 33px, my text is far too short to cover the `div`, and at 33.5px it overflows.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to remedy this? There are lots of plugins for making text fill the whole width of a container, but not for text that has to fill both the width and height. At least, none that I've seen.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.box {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:15%;
    height:500px;
    background:orange;
}
    .box p {
        background:rgba(0,0,0,.1); /* For clarity */
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br><br>
    Suspendisse varius nibh quis urna porttitor, pharetra elementum nisl egestas. Suspendisse libero lacus, faucibus id convallis sit amet, consequat vitae odio.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function responsiveText(){
    var i = 0.5;

    do {
        $(".box p").css("font-size",(i) + "px");

        var textHeight          =  $(".box p").height(),
            containerHeight     =  $(".box").height();
        i += 0.5;   

    } while ( textHeight < containerHeight );           // While the height of the paragraph block is less than the height of the container, run the do...while loop.
} responsiveText();


$(window).resize(function(e) {
    responsiveText();
});
</script>
</body>
```

[image: Text set at 33px. It is too short.]
Text set at 33px. It is too short.

[image: Text set at 33.5px. It overflows.]
Text set at 33.5px. It overflows.

Comment: Find the largest font size that fits (33px in your example) then fiddle with the `line-height` to make the text fit more exactly?

Comment: @RichieHindle Interesting. The only thing is that the code I made puts the font-size at 33.5px because at 33px, the paragraph isn't yet as high as the container...

Comment: You need to back off by one step when you detect the overflow.  Then do a similar loop to increase the `line-height`, again backing off by a step when it overflows.

Comment: Richie's idea is great. I made you this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/2y6z3rsc/ . It makes the text a bit bigger than the container, then defines the ratio between the text and the box and sets the line-height to that ratio. It seems to work on page load, but when resizing it's buggy. When you resize and refresh it works again... maybe someone can build further on this code.

Comment: You could try using `text-align: justify` to get it to fill the width, and then use an appropriate font size to fill the height.

Comment: @LinkinTED Thanks! I had the same problem actually, it doesn't quite work when resizing the page. But your code is at least working

Comment: What if you try with `em` (instead of `px`)? http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I adjusted your function](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/0yqb82qn/1/) to use `em` units instead of `px`, and adjusted the increment from "0.5" to "0.003".

The preview pane is a little unreliable, so [check it out in its own window](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jhfrench/0yqb82qn/1/show/).

Keep in mind:

- The larger the increment, the fewer loop iterations (and the less
  processing).
- The smaller the increment, the "finer" the adjustment
  and the result.

Comment: PS--this also uses @LinkinTED's method for adjusting the line height.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's almost there. The text sometimes overflows just a little... Perhaps we could make the paragraph stop resizing when it reaches 10px from the container height; just so there's definitely no overflow.

Comment: If you intend for this function to be used for multiple "boxes", consider a percentage based "good enough" evaluation (as opposed to a defined number of pixels).