# Resize paragraph of text to fill height

Tags: jquery, text, paragraph

I have a `<p>` with some text in it, I would like to adjust the font size so the text fills the entire height of the element. I have found a bunch of jquery plugins that resize text to fill parent width but nothing for height.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25528559/1430996

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried messing this the css?

An example:
`<p style="font-size:13px" >`

Comment: The point is that the text needs the dynamically resize. I do not know what size the parent is going to be.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you edited the text based on the height of the paragraph element it would be impossible to edit it so it could stick with the width on the other hand you can edit the height of the element based on the height of the text by using this syntax 
`$(selector).height(value)` like this :

```
<p id="dynamic">some text</p>
```

jquery code :

```
$('#dynamic').height($('#dynamic').contents().find('html').height())
```